# Getting coefficients of terms in Sympy equation

Tags: python, sympy

I have the following code. I'm looking for the a,b,c,d terms of the `planeL` variable.
When I print the equation, I can see that it is:
`Eq(14*x + 12*y + 8*z - 102, 0)`

I'm looking to get 14, 12, 8 and -102

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

```
t = sympy.Symbol('t')
s = sympy.Symbol('s')
x = sympy.Symbol('x')
y = sympy.Symbol('y')
z = sympy.Symbol('z')

L = sympy.Matrix([2*t+5, -t+4, -2*t-2])
K = sympy.Matrix([-2*s+3, 5*s-5,-4*s+4])
dirL = sympy.Matrix([2,-1,-2])
dirK = sympy.Matrix([-2,5,-4])
normV = dirL.cross(dirK)
print("The normal vector to the two planes: ", normV)

L0 = L.subs(t,0)
K0 = K.subs(s,0)
print("L0: ", L0, "K0: ", K0)

#Calculating the equation of the planes

planeL = sympy.Eq(normV[0]*(x-L0[0])+normV[1]*(y-L0[1])+normV[2]*(z-L0[2]),0)
planeK = sympy.Eq(normV[0]*(x-K0[0])+normV[1]*(y-K0[1])+normV[2]*(z-K0[2]),0)
print("planeL: ", planeL, "planeK: ", planeK)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following to the end of your code

```
print(sympy.Poly(planeL, x,y,z).coeffs())
```

output:

```
[14, 12, 8, -102]
```